# Displaying an image on API endpoint using aws lambda and node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Right now I am editing the code inline on AWS lambda. This is what I have currently:

```
var qrImage = require('qr-image');


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return sendRes(200,'hi');
};
/*
const sendRes = (status, body) => {
  var response = {
    statusCode: status,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/html"
    },
    body: body
  };
  return response;
}; 
*/

const sendRes = (status, body) => {
  const svg_string = qrImage.imageSync('http://www.nodejs.org',{ type: 'png', size: 20 });
  var response = {
    statusCode: status,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    body: svg_string
  };
  return response;
};
```

This outputs the text Internal server error.

The code below creates a png file and stores it. The functionality I would like on lambda is to simply display the image(No saving involved) when I access the endpoint. But I am not sure how to go about it (New to Lamda, Node.js). What exactly should I be looking into?

```
var qrImage = require('qr-image');
var fs = require('fs');

qrImage
    .image("http://www.nodejs.org", {type:'png', size:20})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("MyQRCode.png"));
```

**EDIT**
I made some small changes and this appears to be working

```
var qrImage = require('qr-image');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return sendRes(200,'hi');
};

const sendRes = (status, body) => {
  const svg_string = qrImage.imageSync('this is AWS!', { type: 'svg', size: 10 });
  var response = {
    statusCode: status,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "image/svg+xml"
    },
    body: svg_string
  };
  return response;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only returning the image with the help of lambda then sync will also work, here the code for it

```
const sendRes = (status, body) => {
  const svg_string = qr.imageSync('http://www.nodejs.org', { type: 'png', size: 20 });
  var response = {
    statusCode: status,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    body: svg_string
  };

  return response;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Just an additional question, do I have to upload the code as a zip with the libraries or can I manually add the library to the inline editor? The second seems easier but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: I guess you are asking about lambda? If so let me clear first I don't have much experience on lambda, I have seen people directly pushing code with all dependencies to lambda in a zip.

Comment: Yes this lamda thing is new to me as well. I am trying that right now.

Comment: Hey I'll update my question. For some reason I am getting internal server error. I do not have cloud watch logs set up so it does not show the exact reason why it is not working but I'll try to get the logs.

Comment: I made some changes and it is working now. Thanks once again!